# Multithreading: TaskExecutor config and CPU Core relation

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, rest

I have an application where I have exposed a REST-API endpoint of POST method. Input data is posted in there and doing some trivial internal data validation, it saves that data to two different database-one is relation DB and another is a third party file storage system i.e s3.
My spring boot application has been configured as such for multithreading:

```
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(6);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(50);
        return executor;
    }
```

I know what these figures mentioned above mean.
So far, so good. The API works fine.

Now, someone wants to post data in that API from outside. He is calling the REST endpoint from a loop of **`100000`** times- so **`100000`** times API call from same loop! It is getting timeout.

Let's say my server config is: corei-5, 4 core, 1 thread of each core-4 threads total, RAM 16GB[I might be wrong, just assume these config is correct].

**So, my questions are:**

1. Getting timeout for such API calling, isn't it reasonable?
2. How threading concept from HW to App taskexecutor co-relate?
   Is it like: when a request comes in to my service, it initiates a thread from threadpool(defined in taskexecutor) which takes the task, and that is handled by a thread of a core i.e thread-1 from core-1, and so on- upto task 4.
   Let's say, each task takes 500ms to complete, so if more than 5 tasks are submitted within this time, the 5th task needs to wait right? Let's say instead of 5, tasks submitted have exceeded the queue max size-50 within 500ms. What happens then?
   Will the service denounce the rest of them?

***Note:That particular endpoint has no async method or future/completablefeature call.***

I actually need to understand the co-relation here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no easy answer to this as it all depends on the processor architecture and maybe even the java implementation in use. \

Comment: can't say about the processor architecture right now but about java impl- the REST-API has no parallel process. I mean to say, the tasks inside the API are consecutive, one after another. Please let me know if you need any info.

Comment: Also if it is a rest endpoint the `TaskExecutor` doesn't do anything as that ishandled by tomcat. Unless your service is annotated with `@Async` or you are using async features of Spring MVC / WebFlux.

Comment: my service method is not annotated wth `@Async` annotation or no async feature is applied in the api. It can be running as a jar file or in a tomcat.

Comment: Then this `TaskExecutor` doesn't do anything but take up memory.

Comment: can you please explain the case I mentioned here? I have some `@Async` annotated service, thought this is relevant, so mentioned here. But I need to know the holistic situation for my case mentioned.

Comment: As stated there is no easy answer as it depends on the implementation of java and your processor architecture what will happen.